# Notifications IOS apns

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have completed my testing and all notifications are going through nicely using php apns. Now as soon as I switch to production I get this result

```
Tue, 16 Oct 2012 16:40:48 +0200 ApnsPHP[5709]: INFO: Trying ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195... 
Tue, 16 Oct 2012 16:40:51 +0200 ApnsPHP[5709]: INFO: Connected to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195. 
Tue, 16 Oct 2012 16:40:51 +0200 ApnsPHP[5709]: INFO: Sending messages queue, run #1: 1 message(s) left in queue. 
Tue, 16 Oct 2012 16:40:51 +0200 ApnsPHP[5709]: STATUS: Sending message ID 1 [custom identifier: Message-Badge-3] (1/3): 119 bytes. 
Tue, 16 Oct 2012 16:40:51 +0200 ApnsPHP[5709]: INFO: Disconnected.
```

This looks fine to me however my device does not receive the notification.

Please Help

Comment: Make sure you're using the correct push certificate for the production environment. Use separate files (don't put keys/certificates for multiple environments in the same file).

Comment: do you use .pem file generated from distribution certificate and distribution provision profile now or do you still use developer ones?

Comment: Check if the app on the device has the correct provisioning profile?

Comment: I use the production pem file

Comment: I get a id from the device so I presume that the provisioning profile is correct

Comment: Also, make sure your deviceToken is the production one.  DeviceTokens for Dev are different then production for the same device.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your DeviceToken is the **production** one. DeviceTokens for **dev** are different then **production** for the same device.

*From Apple*:

*Take note that the device token in the production environment and the device token in the development environment are not the same value.*

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html)